# Salix root password not accepted in terminal, is accepted in GUI boxes

Tags: terminal, passwords, root

When I click a program that requires root password, I enter it and it works.

When I go to the terminal and need to do something that requires the password, it gets rejected.

I've tried many combinations, nothing seems to work. What can be wrong here?

Comment: What command would you execute in terminal?

Comment: Keyboard mapping? Try typing the password in clear text in the terminal (while nobody is standing behind you ;-) ) and see if it comes up as expected.

Comment: @BloodPhilia: I need to edit some apache vhost files.

Comment: Yes, but what is the exact command that invokes the password prompt.

Comment: @BloodPhilia: sudo su -

Comment: And if you use `sudo echo "Hello World"`? Does it also get rejected?

Comment: @user12889: tried it just now, password shows just fine.

Comment: @BloodPhilia: yes, it gets rejected too.

Answer (score 0):

If `sudo su -` does not work, you might have restrictions in your `/etc/sudoers` file. Check, what actions is your user granted in that file.

Another reason might be that your desktop does not use sudo as backend for privilege granting.